# Complex SQL Query Returning Duplicate but varing Values even with key word DISTINCT

Tags: php, sql

I need to return just two sets of data based on the query below but i get four instead

```
SELECT DISTINCT *,
    CASE WHEN likes.face_id    = persona.face_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END liked,
    CASE WHEN dislikes.face_id = persona.face_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END disliked,
    CASE WHEN comments.face_id = persona.face_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END commented
    FROM persona, likes, dislikes, comments
    RIGHT JOIN tagged ON tagged.phone_id = 'FA' WHERE persona.face_id = tagged.face_id
```

below are the tables I am querying from

tagged table :

> ```
>     phone_id    face_id      likeCount     dislikeCount    commentCount 
>        FA         GA             1               1              1            
>        FA         SA             1               0              0
> ```

persona table :

> ```
>         face_id      name      age   
>           GA         Frank     34    
>           SA         Mark      24
> ```

likes table :

> ```
>        face_id           phone_id
>           GA                FA
>           SA                FA
> ```

dislikes table  :

> ```
>        face_id           phone_id
>           SA                FA
> ```

comments table :

> ```
>        face_id           phone_id     comment
>           GA                FA         good
> ```

I get four values (Four sets of data) from the above query instead of two (two sets of data) values

The data set below is the result of the above query when echoed out in php

> "data" :
>   [{"face_id":"GA","likeCount":"1","dislikeCount":"1","commentCount":"1","name":"Mark","age":"34","liked":"1","commented":"1","disliked":"1"},
>
> {"face_id":"SA","likeCount":"1","dislikeCount":"0","commentCount":"0","name":"Frank","age":"24","liked":"0","commented":"0","disliked":"0"},
>
> {"face_id":"GA","likeCount":"1","dislikeCount":"1","commentCount":"1","name":"GA","age":"34","liked":"0","commented":"1","disliked":"1"},
>
> {"face_id":"SA","likeCount":"1","dislikeCount":"0","commentedCount":"0","name":"Frank","age":"24","liked":"1","commented":"0","disliked":"0"}]}

Comment: Fix your query so you are only using explicit `join` syntax.  Mixing explicit and implicit joins is a bad practice and probably the root cause of your problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Please do you mean like this `SELECT DISTINCT *,
  CASE WHEN likes.face_id    = persona.face_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END liked,
  CASE WHEN dislikes.face_id = persona.face_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END disliked,
  CASE WHEN comments.face_id = persona.face_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END commented
  FROM persona, likes, dislikes, comments, tagged
  WHERE tagged.phone_id = '51c7443e8d0cbe28' AND persona.face_id = tagged.face_id`. It still gives me the same result.

Comment: No, I mean get rid of the commas in the `from` clause and replace them with `join` clauses.

Comment: @GordonLinoff replacing the `,` with `JOIN` still gives me the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much more generic approach

```
SELECT * ,
CASE WHEN likes.face_id    = persona.face_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END liked,
CASE WHEN dislikes.face_id = persona.face_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END disliked,
CASE WHEN comments.face_id = tagged.face_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END commented
FROM tagged JOIN persona ON persona.face_id = tagged.face_id 
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.face_id = persona.face_id AND likes.phone_id = 'FA'
LEFT JOIN dislikes ON dislikes.face_id = tagged.face_id AND dislikes.phone_id = 'FA'
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.face_id = tagged.face_id AND comments.phone_id = 'FA'
WHERE tagged.phone_id =  'FA'
```

but there is a problem, the face_ids all come up as null